# Not able to remove cloned list elements

Tags: jquery, clone

I'm cloning list items in a menu and I have an `on click` action on the back link where the cloned elements should be removed.

But they are not removed and each time I click a menu item, the sub menu keeps growing.

I've tried different approaches:

```
$('.portal-sub-menu').empty()
$('.portal-sub-menu').remove()
$('.portal-sub-menu').children().remove()
```

You can see the fiddle here: http://jsfiddle.net/spstieng/MdJsL/8/

Why can't I remove the cloned items?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is a fixed JSFiddle:

http://jsfiddle.net/MdJsL/12/

Updated JS:

```
$('.portal-menu a').click(function () {
    $('.portal-menu').addClass('slide');
    return false;
});

$('.portal-menu > li a').on('click', function () {
    $(this).next().children().clone(true, true).appendTo('.portal-sub-menu');
    $('.portal-sub-menu .back').on('click', function () {
        $('.portal-menu').removeClass('slide')
        setTimeout(function () {
            $('.portal-sub-menu').empty();
        }, 800);
        return false;
    });
});
```

- I removed your `.done()` call - since your animation is happening based on CSS, JavaScript does not know when it is finished.
- Added an 800ms `setTimeout()` call to wait for your CSS animation to finish before emptying `.portal-sub-menu`
- Removed unnecessary `.promise().done(...)` call.

Hope this helps!

Comment: That's brilliant Robert. Why can't we use `.delay(800)` here?

Comment: I could be wrong, but I believe `.delay()` only applies to queued items in jQuery (ie. animations).  Here's a JSFiddle demo: http://jsfiddle.net/Lq5AZ/

Answer (score 0):

It did not worked because `$('.portal-sub-menu').empty();` was not getting called.Try this:

```
$('.portal-sub-menu .back').on('click', function(){
        $('.portal-menu').removeClass('slide')
        $('.portal-sub-menu').empty();
        return false;
    });
```

**[Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/KLxMy/)**

Comment: I know that works. But I'm making a slide in / out menu and removing the menu items before it slides out looks ugly. That's why it's inside the `.promise().done()`

Comment: You should rather set the background to default color..that will prevent that effect

Comment: How will that help? The content will still be blank before the slider shuts.

Comment: yes but you can set the color to container itself .

Comment: I still don't understand how that will help. The content / menu items should not be removed before the menu has slid out of view.